# How to get rid of <U+FEFF> in a R data.table column name?

Tags: r, data.table

In order to import a large dataset I've used data.table with the option integer64 = "character" because some columns have very large numbers that were truncated otherwise, and are just identifiers.

```
my <- fread("mydata.csv", encoding="UTF-8",integer64 = "character")
```

With that option enabled those columns are imported properly as characters but now I have a problem, their columnnames have being automatically modified to start with these character

```
<U+FEFF>
```

For example the first column now is called

```
<U+FEFF>ID_2006_2011
```

The problem now is that I can't work with those names, for example:

```
> miniDT[1,"<U+FEFF>ID_2006_2011", with=F]
Error in `[.data.table`(miniDT, 1, "<U+FEFF>ID_2006_2011", with = F) : 
  column(s) not found: <U+FEFF>ID_2006_2011
> miniDT[1,"ID_2006_2011", with=F]
Error in `[.data.table`(miniDT, 1, "ID_2006_2011", with = F) : 
  column(s) not found: ID_2006_2011
```

How can I work with them?
How can I change them to something simpler?
I've tried with

```
setnames(miniDT, "ID_2006_2011", "ID")
```

but I get this error:

> Error in setnames(miniDT, "ID_2006_2011", "ID") :    Items of 'old'
>   not found in column names: ID_2006_2011

The column name  is really there because...:

```
> miniDT[1,1, with=F]
   <U+FEFF>ID_2006_2011
1:         160701000002
```

For the moment I'll do it using numbers instead of names to refer to the columns.

Comment: No reproducible example to test.. but already fixed in current devel, [#1087](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1087).

Comment: But this seems to be fixed on data.table 1.9.8.  I'm using 1.9.7 Is there any workaround in my case?
I've tried to export just a small part of the dataset, but then it doesn't produce the error, I don't know why.

Comment: I can't do much without having the file to test.

Comment: @Arun I've sent it to you the object saved with save().

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and found that `readLines()` with `encoding="UTF-8-BOM"` didn't actually remove it.  I used the following function to strip out the BOM:

```
removeBOM <- function(headers){
  gsub("\\xef\\xbb\\xbf", "", headers, useBytes = T)
}
```